# Example of Artinian ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-verification

By definition a ring $R$ is Artinian if it is Artinian as $R$-module. I think the following is an example of an Artinian ring:  $\mathbb Q / \mathbb Z$.

Ideals in it are of the form $(\frac1n)$ (since $(\frac{1}{n_1}, \dots , \frac{1}{n_k}) = (\frac{1}{\text{lcm}_i(n_i)})$).

Since we have $(\frac1n) \subset (\frac1m)$ if and only if $n$ divides $m$, every decreasing chain stabilizes eventually since $n$ only has finitely many divisors.

Is this correct?

Comment: How is $\mathbb Q / \mathbb Z$ a ring?

Comment: Related to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142597/noetherian-and-artinian-modules.

Comment: I'm confused :,(

Comment: Or is the question whether $\mathbb Q / \mathbb Z$ is an Artinian $\mathbb Z$-module?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: It is not a ring since 1 is not there. Theres no requirement on modules to have identity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'd have to tell me how $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$ is a ring. The notation suggests that $\mathbb Z$ is an ideal of $\mathbb Q$ (which it isn't) and that we're forming the factor ring.

One way to make commutative Artinian rings is to fix a field $k$ and look at finite dimensional $k$-algebras. Geometrically these correspond to finite sets of points in affine space. In the classical setting these will look like $\prod k$, but it's interesting to think about stuff like $\mathbb R[x]/(x^2 + 1) \simeq \mathbb C$ and $k[x]/(x^2)$.