# Give an example of a ring $A$ such that $\dim(A) =0$ but $A$ is not a field.

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

> Give an example of a ring $A$ such that $\dim(A) =0$ but $A$ is **not** a field.

One thing is sure, $A$ cannot be an integral domain.

Comment: Hint: Consider a very small finite ring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

let $k$ be a field. consider $k \times k$ (pointwise multiplication).

Comment: But $k\times k$ will be an integral domain. But for the conditions to be satisfied, we need an example that should not be an integral domain.

Comment: @chi $k\times k$ is certainly not an integral domain; $(1, 0) \cdot (0, 1) = (0, 0)$.

Comment: But $<(k,0)>$ will be a prime ideal in $k \times k$ . Therefore, dimension  $\neq 0$

Comment: @chi the dimension is the number of primes in a maximal prime chain minus one. this ring contains exactly two primes, and they're not nested, so the dimension is zero. The spectrum of this ring is two closed points.

Comment: We have $<(0,0)> \subset <(k,0)>$ which are nested and prime.

Comment: @chi < (0, 0) > is not prime, because, as we just discussed, $k \times k$ is not an integral domain

Comment: Ok, Got it now!

Answer (score 2):

"*Steps in Commutative Algebra*" by "*R. Y. Sharp*" has:

> 8.39 LEMMA. Let $R$ be a commutative **Artinian** ring. Then every prime ideal of $R$ is maximal.

So every **Artinian** ring which is not a field, is an answer to your question.
 For examples of Artinian rings see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/173633/example-of-artinian-ring) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artinian_ring). Also if you are familiar with localization, you can easily see that if $p$ is a minimal prime ideal of $R$, then $R_p$ is artinian.

Comment: did you see Dylan Moreland 's answer?

Answer (score 1):

Let $R$ be a *Boolean* ring other than $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

> **Lemma** *The only integral domain that is Boolean is $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$,* for otherwise, if $R$ an integral domain but $R \neq Z/2Z$, we may take $a \neq 0, 1$. But $a \cdot (a-1) = a^2 - a = a - a = 0$ a contradiction.

Hence, *Every prime ideal $P$ of $R$ is maximal*, since $R/P$ is boolean and integral implies $R/P \simeq \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ a field. Therefore, $dim R = 0$.